# Test cases are not executing after spring-boot upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am migrating from Spring boot version **2.1.13.RELEASE** to **2.4.2** version.

Along with Spring version, I have also upgraded the maven plugin version as follows:

Old:

```
<maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
<maven-dependency-check-plugin.version>4.0.2</maven-dependency-check-plugin.version>
<maven-frontend-plugin.version>1.7.6</maven-frontend-plugin.version>
maven-gmaven-plugin.version>1.6.3</maven-gmaven-plugin.version>
<maven-jacoco-plugin.version>0.8.5</maven-jacoco-plugin.version>
<maven-pmd-plugin.version>3.12.0</maven-pmd-plugin.version>
<maven-spotbugs-plugin.version>3.1.12.2</maven-spotbugs-plugin.version>
<maven-spring-cloud-contract-plugin.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</maven-spring-cloud-contract-plugin.version>
<maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
```

New :

```
<maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
<maven-dependency-check-plugin.version>6.0.4</maven-dependency-check-plugin.version>
<maven-frontend-plugin.version>1.8.0</maven-frontend-plugin.version>
<maven-gmaven-plugin.version>1.12.1</maven-gmaven-plugin.version>
<maven-jacoco-plugin.version>0.8.6</maven-jacoco-plugin.version>
<maven-pmd-plugin.version>3.14.0</maven-pmd-plugin.version>
<maven-spotbugs-plugin.version>4.2.0</maven-spotbugs-plugin.version>
<maven-spring-cloud-contract-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-spring-cloud-contract-plugin.version>
<maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
```

After upgrading, my test cases are not getting executed.
it doesn't throw any error.It just print below lines:

[INFO] Results:

[INFO]

**[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0**

Before upgrading it is to print below:

[INFO] Results:

[INFO]

**[INFO] Tests run: 69, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0**

Any guidance about the above issue is appreciated.

Comment: How are you declaring your tests `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` or `org.junit.Test`?

Comment: @geobreze I am using "org.junit.Test" in my testcases

Comment: I would recommend you to migrate your tests to JUnit 5 but as a temporary solution, try adding dependency `org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine`